# SQL Server aggregating data that may contain multiple copies

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am working on some software where I need to do large aggregation of data using SQL Server. The software is helping people play poker better. The query I am using at the moment looks like this:

```
Select H, sum(WinHighCard + ChopHighCard + WinPair + ChopPair + Win2Pair + Chop2Pair + Win3OfAKind + Chop3OfAKind + WinStraight + ChopStraight + WinFlush + ChopFlush + WinFullHouse + ChopFullHouse + WinQuads + ChopQuads + WinStraightFlush + ChopStraightFlush) / Count(WinStraightFlush) as ResultTotal
 from [FlopLookup].[dbo].[_5c3c3d] 
                inner join[FlopLookup].[dbo].[Lookup5c3c3d] on [FlopLookup].[dbo].[Lookup5c3c3d].[id] = [FlopLookup].[dbo].[_5c3c3d].[id] 
                where (H IN (1164, 1165, 1166) ) AND 
                (V IN (1260, 1311))
                Group by H;
```

This works fine and is the fastest way I have found to do what I am trying to achieve. The problem is I need to enhance the functionality in a way that allows the aggregation to include multiple instances of V. So for example in the above query instead of it just including the data from 1260 and 1311 once it may need to include 1260 twice and 1311 three times. But obviously just saying

```
V IN (1260, 1260, 1311, 1311, 1311)
```

won't work because each unique value is only counted once in an IN clause.

I have come up with a solution to this problem which works but seems rather clunky. I have created another lookup table which just takes the values between 0 and 1325 and assigns them to a field called V1 and for each V1 there are 100 V2 values that for e.g. for V1 = 1260 there is a range from 126000 through to 126099 for the V2 values. Then in the main query I join to this table and do the lookup like this:

```
Select H, sum(WinHighCard + ChopHighCard + WinPair + ChopPair + Win2Pair + Chop2Pair + Win3OfAKind + Chop3OfAKind + WinStraight + ChopStraight + WinFlush + ChopFlush + WinFullHouse + ChopFullHouse + WinQuads + ChopQuads + WinStraightFlush + ChopStraightFlush) / Count(WinStraightFlush) as ResultTotal
 from [FlopLookup].[dbo].[_5c3c3d] 
                inner join[FlopLookup].[dbo].[Lookup5c3c3d] on [FlopLookup].[dbo].[Lookup5c3c3d].[id] = [FlopLookup].[dbo].[_5c3c3d].[id] 
                inner join[FlopLookup].[dbo].[VillainJoinTable] on [FlopLookup].[dbo].[VillainJoinTable].[V1] = [FlopLookup].[dbo].[_5c3c3d].[V]
                where (H IN (1164, 1165, 1166) ) AND 
                (V2 IN (126000, 126001, 131100, 131101, 131102) )
                Group by H;
```

So although it works it is quite slow. It feels inefficient because it is adding data multiple times when what would probably be more appropriate is a way of doing this using multiplication, i.e. instead of passing in 126000, 126001, 126002, 126003, 126004, 126005, 126006, 126007 I instead pass in 1260 in the original query and then multiply it by 8. But I have not been able to work out a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT - Added more information at the request of Livius in the comments**

H stands for "Hero" and is in the table _5c3c3d as a smallint representing the two cards the player is holding (e.g. AcKd, Js4h etc.). V stands for "Villain" and is similar to Hero but represents the cards the opponent is holding similarly encoded. The encoding and decoding takes place in the code. These two fields form the clustered index for the _5c3c3d table. The remaining field in this table is Id which is another smallint which is used to join with the table Lookup5c3c3d which contains all the equity information for the hero's hand against the villain's hand for the flop 5c3c3d.

V2 is just a field in a table I have created to try and resolve the problem described by having a table called VillainJoinTable which has V1 (which maps directly to V in _5c3c3d via a join) and V2 which can potentially contain 100 numbers per V1 (e.g. when V1 is 1260 it could contain 126000, 126001 ... 126099). This is in order to allow me to create an "IN" clause that can effectively have multiple lookups to equity information for the same V multiple times.

Here are some screenshots:

Structure of the three tables

[image: Structure of the three tables]

Some data from _5c3c3d

[image: Some data from _5c3c3d]

Some data from Lookup5c3c3d

[image: Some data from Lookup5c3c3d]

Some data from VillainJoinTable

[image: Some data from VillainJoinTable]

Comment: Will be better if you show some sample data and result. And what is `H` what is `V2`? Without DDL we do not know from which table it is..

Comment: Thanks Livius. I have updated the main body with more information.